# Download a module for a different core version?

Tags: 8, composer

I'm using Drush 10, and I can't use `dl` to download a module, since the command was removed to push Composer use.

Is there a way to download a Drupal 7 module into a Drupal 8 site using Composer, so that I can use the [Drupal 7 to 8/9 Module Upgrader](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalmoduleupgrader) script on it?

The project I want to download doesn't have a Drupal 8 version yet, and it has no composer.json.

Comment: If you're locked locally to Drush 10, you can use a docker hub image to execute Drush 8 to do the download (e.g. `docker run -v $(pwd):/app drush/drush:8 dl pathauto`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would just use `wget`.

Copy the Zip file url, ex:

```
sudo wget https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.24.zip
```

and then

```
sudo unzip views-7.x-3.24.zip
```